# Heroku build not communicating with database

Tags: json, reactjs, heroku

My Heroku build won't communicate with my database on mongodb. I have tried running it on localhost 5000 and it works, it just doesnt work when I push to heroku. My server.js is set up like this:

> ```
> const express = require('express')
> const cors = require('cors') 
> const mongoose = require('mongoose')
>
> require('dotenv').config();
>
> const app = express();
> const port = process.env.PORT ||  5000;
>
> app.use(cors());
> app.use(express.json()); 
> app.use(express.static('client/build'));
>
> const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI
> mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true})
>
> const connection = mongoose.connection;
> connection.once('open', () => {
> console.log('mongoDB database connection established successfully')
> })
>
> const exerciseRouter = require('./routes/exercises') 
> const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
>
>
> app.use('/exercises', exerciseRouter)
>  app.use('/users', usersRouter); 
>
> app.listen(port, () => {
> console.log(`server is running on port: ${port}`)
> })
> ```

and the error messages I get when I console.log are:

> xhr.js:184 POST https://fitnesspush.herokuapp.com/%20users/add 404
> (Not Found) (anonymous) @ xhr.js:184 e.exports @ xhr.js:13 e.exports @
> dispatchRequest.js:50 Promise.then (async) l.request @ Axios.js:61
> r.forEach.l. @ Axios.js:86 (anonymous) @ bind.js:9 value @
> create-user.component.js:29 u @ react-dom.production.min.js:14 d @
> react-dom.production.min.js:14 (anonymous) @
> react-dom.production.min.js:14 v @ react-dom.production.min.js:15 it @
> react-dom.production.min.js:52 ot @ react-dom.production.min.js:51 ut
> @ react-dom.production.min.js:52 dt @ react-dom.production.min.js:56 I
> @ react-dom.production.min.js:287 W @ react-dom.production.min.js:19
> Jt @ react-dom.production.min.js:70 Gt @
> react-dom.production.min.js:69 t.unstable_runWithPriority @
> scheduler.production.min.js:19
>
> zo @ react-dom.production.min.js:122 A @
> react-dom.production.min.js:287 Kt @ react-dom.production.min.js:68
> createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with
> status code 404
> at e.exports (createError.js:16)
> at e.exports (settle.js:17)
> at XMLHttpRequest.d.onreadystatechange (xhr.js:69) e.exports @ createError.js:16 e.exports @ settle.js:17 d.onreadystatechange @
> xhr.js:69 Promise.then (async) value @ create-user.component.js:30 u @
> react-dom.production.min.js:14 d @ react-dom.production.min.js:14
> (anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:14 v @
> react-dom.production.min.js:15 it @ react-dom.production.min.js:52 ot
> @ react-dom.production.min.js:51 ut @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
> dt @ react-dom.production.min.js:56 I @
> react-dom.production.min.js:287 W @ react-dom.production.min.js:19 Jt
> @ react-dom.production.min.js:70 Gt @ react-dom.production.min.js:69
> t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19 zo @
> react-dom.production.min.js:122 A @ react-dom.production.min.js:287 Kt
> @ react-dom.production.min.js:68

my package.json in my client folder looks like this:

> {   "version": "0.1.0",
> "private": true,    "dependencies": {
> "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
> "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
> "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
> "axios": "^0.20.0",
> "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
> "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
> "react": "^16.13.1",
> "react-datepicker": "^3.1.3",
> "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
> "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
> "react-scripts": "^3.4.3"   },   "scripts": {
> "start": "react-scripts start",
> "build": "react-scripts build",
> "test": "react-scripts test",
> "eject": "react-scripts eject"
> },   "eslintConfig": {
> "extends": "react-app"   },   "browserslist": {
> "production": [
> ">0.2%",
> "not dead",
> "not op_mini all"
> ],
> "development": [
> "last 1 chrome version",
> "last 1 firefox version",
> "last 1 safari version"
> ]   },   "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/" }

and this is the one in my root folder:

> {   "name": "backend",
> "main": "index.js",
> "scripts": {
> "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
> "build": "cd client && npm run build",
> "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
> "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
> "start": "node server.js",
> "client": "cd client && npm start",
> "dev": "concurrently -n 'server,client' -c 'red,green'  "nodemon server.js" "npm run client""   },
> "author": "",
> "license": "ISC",
> "dependencies": {
> "cors": "^2.8.5",
> "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
> "express": "^4.17.1",
> "mongoose": "^5.10.0"   }
> }"version": "1.0.0",
> "description": "",

Comment: Did you checked the IP access list in your Atlas cluster. I think the problem is related to this

Comment: It appears the problem is coming from your users/add route. Can you show us that route?

Comment: Did you add a mongo DB addon and check the docs for that? Heroku isn't going to let you host a DB within the app's server,